# jquery. How to remove last character if the last character is `)`. Why different browsers differently show base64 code?

Tags: jquery

Here is example https://jsfiddle.net/ry2jaxdu/7/

Open with Firefox or IE, see ending with `CIrKDQUAADs=")`. There is `")`

But if open with Chrome, Opera or Safari, see ending with `CIrKDQUAADs=)`. There is only `)`, without `"`.

I need to remove `")`.

Used code like `mod_val = mod_val.replace('")', '');`

As for Chrome, Opera and Safari code is different, added also `mod_val = mod_val.replace(')', '');`

But there may be possibility, that remaining part of `base64` code contain `)`.

So question is how to remove last character if the last character is `)`?

And another not so important question: why above mentioned differences for browsers?

Update... while wrote the question found answer `mod_val = mod_val.replace(/\)$/, '');`

But remains the second question why such differences....

Comment: I don't get it, you ask two questions here, then say that we should only answer the second... And the only answer that answers the first question only gets marked as the accepted one...?

Comment: @Salketer ... yes, sorry. In accepted answer saw different way to get the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can strip off the `url(` and trailing `)` like so:

```
base64_img.replace(/^url\("?|"?\)$/g, '')
```

Answer (score 2):

That is simply how the background-image CSS rule is parsed by the different browsers... some will parse it one way, others will parse it another way...

```
background-image:url('logo.jpg');
```

Note the single quotes in URL, but using javascript they return their parsed version...

```
//In IE
background-image='url("logo.jpg")'
//In Chrome
background-image='url(logo.jpg)'
```

Answer (score 1):

The difference in browser is not exactly based on the character and its base64. It is the way the browser deals with the (here)`url` parameter of `background-image`.

For eg:
Chrome removes off the enclosure and picks the content of the parameter and puts it in its own way without any quotes.
Whereas Firefox picks the content and always puts it in double quotes `"`.